# Running Ubuntu from External Hard Drive

Tags: grub2, external-hdd

Hey everyone I'm having issues with running Ubuntu 13.10 off an external drive I have hooked up to my laptop (HP DV6 Windows 7)  via USB. 
Anyhow, I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on a hard drive which is inside an external hard drive enclosure. I know that installation was successful (i.e. grub runs and boots it) because I can boot from the external drive from public computers (school desktops) where I see the grub menu and simply run from there.

I can further attest to this as my brother's HP laptop which is just one year newer than mine can boot from the external HD, and I've even been able to boot Windows 7 from the external hd (that's a different story but the same principle I believe.)

However, when I have it connected to my laptop and set the BIOS to boot from the external hard drive, all I get is a black screen followed by nothing else happening - Ubuntu isn't loaded and I have to hard restart my laptop.

The only thing I've been able to see is "GRUB loading." when I hold the shift key upon attempting to boot from the external drive.

Someone please help! I've been trying to get this to work for a good 2 months with no luck. I can run the liveUSB no problem as well. I initially thought it was a problem with the BIOS but with it being able to boot Windows 7 from that very external drive leads me to believe otherwise. I've even tried running Boot-Repair with no luck, simply causing the GRUB rescue screen to appear as opposed to a black screen.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My initial guess is that the video drivers may not be working and your Ubuntu is unable to automatically configure, but this is just a guess. You said you can see GRUB loading. Do you get a GRUB menu? Have you tried pressing alt-f2 during the black parts?

Answer (score 0):

Your Bios Probably doesn't support grub from external hdd booting. Try doing a full install in your Hard Drive without grub (Select Clear Hard Drive and install). That had worked for me while i was using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Good Luck !